# How to select table row elements inside a particular div with a given id

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select all the `<tr>` elements inside a **tbody** and attach a click event by jquery but I just can not select the right elements.

This is my code:

```
    <div id="wrapper" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <table>
          <tbody>
           <tr id="row_2">
           <tr id="row_3">
           <tr id="row_4">

...
```

and I tried to selct all the tr's like that:

```
 $('#wrapper tr').mousedown(function(event) {

and 

$('#wrapper > tr').mousedown(function(event) {
```

but it doesn't bind the click event at all.

Comment: That looks like invalid HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method. Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
 $('#wrapper').find('tr')
```

Comment: How is this different form `$('#wrapper tr')`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like invalid HTML. Use proper markup like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>           
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And now bind the click event.

```
$('#wrapper tr').mousedown(function(event) {
    //do something...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An alias of the [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method is adding a second parameter to the selector: `$('tr', '#wrapper')`.
And maybe add the `table` tag if it's not present in your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You already given id attribute to each row so easily you can access each row by using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector seems to be allright. Maybe you should use .click instead of .mousedown
Also, have you put the event bindings within a document load function?
Besides, I think it's weird you don't have a table element. But that shouldnt be the problem.

Create a jsfiddle if you need us to give a better look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#wrapper').find('tr').mousedown(function(event) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an each but you must specify the table or element

```js
$('#clk').on('click', function(){
   let trs="";
   $("#wrapper #table2 tbody tr").each(function(i){
       trs+=this.innerHTML;
   });
   alert(trs)
})
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table> 
<table id="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>$800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>May</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table> 
</div>

<button type="button" id="clk">Clickme</button>
```